# how to make a jQuery event apply to all selected elements including the ones added as a consequence of the event?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a function that adds a h1 for each h1 clicked, I have coded one that works, but it only works with the original h1, and the newly added h1s do not generate anything when clicked.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("h1").click(function(){
              $("body").after("<h1>this is an added header</h1>");
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best using a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for this:

```
$("body").on("click", "h1", function(event){
    $(this).after("<h1>...</h1>");
});
```

Basically, there's only one event handler on the body that's firing if a `click` event happens from within a `h1` tag. It's inefficient to repeat the same listener multiple times across different elements, especially when you need future elements to trigger that behaviour too. That's precisely one of the reasons why delegated handlers exist.

Comment: I am not sure why your answer's function is not working

Comment: @Adam Substitute `$("body")` for `$(body)`. Believe Alhadis was attempting to convey that `$("body")` selector could be cached; which would  also remove need to call `jQuery()` again. E.g.; `var body = $("body"); body.on("click", function() {body.append("<h1></h1>")})`

Comment: Ignore the `$(body).append("<h1></h1>");` part - that was just a rough placeholder for you to swap out with your own handler code. And yes, guest271314 is right, `"body"` should be quoted so it becomes a CSS selector.

Comment: @Alhadis You could avoid calling `jQuery()` three times by caching `$("body")` selector; which, fwiw, could also be done at own Answer

Comment: @guest271314 `jQuery` is only being called twice, and I already stated that the containing code of the callback was a placeholder. Furthermore, I think you mean "assigning to a variable" instead of "caching selector".

Comment: @guest271314 ok I have substituted it and it worked, I tried to replace ("body").append with ("h1").append, but the size of the added h1s keeps increasing exponentially

Comment: @Alhadis Actually presumed you were attempting to cache selector, or assign to variable, by using `$(body)`; where prior to two at post `var body = $("body")`; instead you were only providing an example of a pattern; yes, only twice; though once for each time handler called

Comment: @Adam _"I tried to replace ("body").append with ("h1").append"_ Are you actually trying to append an `h1` to the same `h1` clicked?

Comment: @guest271314 You are *seriously* making this topic far more complicated than it needs to be. The submitter asked how to have an event listener register for future events, not what the most efficient way of storing object references is.

Comment: @guest271314 no I'm trying to do it the same way Alhadis' function works, I am just confused why $("body").append is used rather than $("h1").append, and I also want to know why h1's size keeps increasing exponentially I am new to programming been only a month

Comment: @Adam `$("h1").append()` appends `h1` to each `<h1>` element in `document` at each click on an `<h1>` element; there should only be one `<body>` element

Comment: @Alhadis Not complicated, actually. You pointed out that using `$(document)` as parent was not necessary; similary calling `jQuery()` at each `click` event is not necessary. OP perhaps gains perspective from both points?

Comment: I think we're on two different pages here: also, I'm coming seriously close to stating *jQuery* is not necessary, but that's not going to help the submitter... I'm also confused as to what you mean by `parent`. Explain?

Comment: @Alhadis Event delegation is essentially attaching event to dynamic element `parentElement`. `document.body` is `parent` of `h1` , `document` is parent of `body` and `h1`

Comment: ... uh no, that's not correct at all. Event delegation works by testing the selector of an event's target. It has nothing to do with attaching events to objects dynamically whatsoever. Doing so would add obvious overhead.

Comment: @Alhadis See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) _"Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future."_ , closer to your description [Events and Event Delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) _"The bubbling behavior of events allows us to do "event delegation" — binding handlers to high-level elements, and then detecting which low-level element initiated the event."_

Comment: Oh Christ, please don't play "read the docs" on me. It uses the phrasing "attach a single event listener to a parent element" to simplify the explanation of how it operates. Internally, it uses selector matching to identify the relevant element. Obviously newcomers aren't expected to know that. Look... just quit while you're ahead. Seriously.

Comment: @Alhadis  "quit" does not exist, here. Did not state that your description was incorrect. Cheers

Comment: We're clearly on different pages here. I'm dropping this because it's adding nothing of value to the submitter's question, and it's wasting both our time.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $("body"); // cache selector
  $(this).on("click", "h1", function() {
    body.after("<h1>this is an added header</h1>");
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why would I want to use delegate or on rather than after?

Comment: There's no need to wait for the document's `ready` event to fire before attaching the event handler. If you're attaching it directly to the `document` object, you won't need to wait for the document tree to finish parsing.

Comment: _"but why would I want to use delegate or on rather than after?"_ Not certain gather what you mean. The `click` event is attached to `document`; when `h1` elements are appended to `document`, clicks on those dynamically created elements will also be handled by `click` event attached to `document`

Comment: You're better off just binding the handler to `$("body")` instead of using the document object (`$(this)`): `$("body").on("click", "h1", function(){ $(this).after("etc..."); })`

Comment: @Alhadis What do you mean by "better off"? Only direct parent binding is needed?

Comment: @Adam I've updated my answer; I used the wrong function name, sorry. It's been years since I've bothered using jQuery.